# Multiple Inboud Endpoints in Mule ESB Flow?

Tags: mule, soa, esb

I need to support an operation both via SOAP and file dropping on a folder. Most of the logic will be he same. Is it possible to trigger the same flow with two message sources? I cant seem to find a way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a composite message source:

```
<composite-source>
  <file:inbound-endpoint ... />
  <http:inbound-endpoint ... />
</composite-source>
```

If you use CXF, you'll have to stick the service element inside the HTTP inbound endpoint.