# Mule - Multiple endpoint to the same semantic flow

Tags: rest, mule, esb

I have encountered such a design issue when designing an api with Mule ApiKit:

there are both JMS and Http endpoints that we assume the consumers can pick what they prefer to interact, and from either endpiont, the semantic flow is the same.

```
JMS --| 
      |
      |--->do something(semantic)
      |
HTTP--|
```

In actual implementation, we are kind of debating:

option1: merge semantic flow with http endpoint, and if message is from JMS, use http outbound in the jms flow

option2: keep 3 flows - 2 endpoints and 1 semantic separate

We try to implement the SEDA (staged event driven archi), so option1 seems about it, but from contrary side, people is thinking performance will become an issue.

What is your opinion here?

Answer (score 0):

You might try Mule Composite Source. This will help you to accept input from two different source endpoints and then execute the same semantic.

Refer to the following links for more help.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scopes

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Bookstore+Example

[Multiple Inboud Endpoints in Mule ESB Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530337/multiple-inboud-endpoints-in-mule-esb-flow)

Comment: The http endpoint is from apikit, will be interesting have to manually add the composite scope every time the apikit automatically generated its flows